# React-Native geolocation promises not chaining correctly

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native, geolocation, fetch

**Edit: I've cleaned up the async and awaits, also removed duplicate code**

I'm having some issues getting the geolocation to work in conjunction with google's reverse geocoder API. I'm using react-native 0.51 as well as the Fetch API. I've been running and testing my code with Android Studio's Virtual Device Emulator.

```
const convertCoords = (position) => {
  return fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonlatlng=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&key=API-KEY`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((location) => {
    this.setState({
      address: location.results[0].formatted_address,
      longitude: location.results[0].geometry.location.lng,
      latitude: location.results[0].geometry.location.lat
    })
  })
}
```

I'm using the `componentDidMount()` to make my API call inside of this block:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => convertCoords(position),
  (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout:20000, maximumAge: 1000},
)
```

My goal is to set the longitude, latitude and address into the state, that way I can display the address to the user and then hold on to the long and lat to later send to a database.

The problem that I keep running into is most definitely related to the asynchronous nature of JavaScript's Fetch. I keep getting the following error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'response.json')`

I know that there's a better way of handling all of this, looking at Redux to handle my state better. But for now I need to get this up and running.

I also know that my asyncs and awaits are all over the place and probably not necessary/causing the error. I'm not to experienced with react-native, let alone react and was hoping someone could help clear this up for me.

Please feel free to reach out if you need anymore information from me!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code seems to think `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` returns a Promise - it doesn't - oh, wait, the code starting at `then(async (location) => {
  await this.setState({` in the second code block shouldn't be there, right! Because it's duplicated from the convertCoords function

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things with `async`/`await` - there's really no need in such "simple" code

```
const convertCoords = position => fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonlatlng=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&key=API-KEY`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(location => this.setState({
        address: location.results[0].formatted_address,
        longitude: location.results[0].geometry.location.lng,
        latitude: location.results[0].geometry.location.lat
    }));



navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => convertCoords(position),
    error => this.setState({
        error: error.message
    }), {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 1000
    },
)
```

However, I think your real issue is that you seem to have copied some code by mistake

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  async (position) => {
    convertCoords(position)
  },
  (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout:20000, maximumAge: 1000},
) 
// code below shouldn't be there at all, it's a duplicate of `convertCoords` code
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(async (location) => {
  await this.setState({
    address: location.results[0].formatted_address,
    longitude: location.results[0].geometry.location.lng,
    latitude: location.results[0].geometry.location.lat
  })
})
```

Comment: Awesome thank you for catching the repeated code! I've gone ahead and removed all async and awaits from the code. I've edited my original post to reflect what I'm currently working with. I'm still getting the following error `Possible unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this.setState')`